# How to sort dates in ascending order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written this code and works. It shows total amount etc grouped by month year but I want to show months,year in ascending order but it shows them in random sorting i.e. June 2016, May 2016 etc

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, pd.PaymentDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, pd.PaymentDate) AS PDate,
                   SUM(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then PD.PropertyDetailsTotalAmount else 0 END) as CommercialIncome, 
                   SUM(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Residential' then PD.PropertyDetailsTotalAmount else 0 END) as ResidentialIncome,
                   COUNT(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then PD.pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID else NULL END) as TotalCommercialMaps,
                   COUNT(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Residential' then PD.pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID else NULL END) as TotalResidentialMaps,

                   (Count(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then PD.pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID else NULL END)
                   +
                   COUNT(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Residential' then PD.pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID else NULL END)) TotalMaps,

                   (SUM(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then PD.PropertyDetailsTotalAmount else 0 END)
                   +
                   SUM(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Residential' then PD.PropertyDetailsTotalAmount else 0 END)) as TotalIncome

            From PropertyDetails PD
            Inner Join Properties P
            ON PD.fk_Properties_ID= p.pk_Properties_ID
            Inner Join PropertyTypes PT
            ON PT.pk_PropertyTypes_PropertyTypeID= P.fk_PropertyTypes_ID
            where
            PD.Paid= 1 
            and PaymentDate >= @DateFrom AND PaymentDate < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo)
            Group By DATENAME(MONTH, pd.PaymentDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, pd.PaymentDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the group by to

```
Group By DATENAME(MONTH, pd.PaymentDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, pd.PaymentDate), DatePART(Month, pd.PaymentDate), DatePart(YEAR, pd.PaymentDate)
order by DatePart(YEAR, pd.PaymentDate) asc, DatePART(Month, pd.PaymentDate) asc
```

Or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
group by DATENAME(MONTH,pd.PaymentDate) ,DATENAME(YEAR,pd.PaymentDate),MONTH(pd.PaymentDate),YEAR(pd.PaymentDate)
order by YEAR(pd.PaymentDate) asc,MONTH(pd.PaymentDate) asc
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple as

```
....
group by DATENAME(MONTH,pd.PaymentDate) , DATENAME(YEAR,pd.PaymentDate),MONTH(pd.PaymentDate), YEAR(pd.PaymentDate)
order by YEAR(pd.PaymentDate) desc, MONTH(pd.PaymentDate) desc
```

Comment: Column "PropertyDetails.PaymentDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @FannyKhan My bad, I totally missed you had a `group by` this should work.